# &makeprofile=1 parameter no longer works

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I made several apps that invited the user to create pictures, uploaded them to facebook and then sent them to a link on facebook that allowed them to set them as their profile picture:
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152753169290428&makeprofile=1

In the last few days, facebook is just ignoring the makeprofile parameter. I just love developing for facebook, it's such a roller coaster ride.

Can anyone help? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Where is the makeprofile parameter defined? If it wasn't defined I'm not surprised it stopped working. If it is documented please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect to the mobile URL like:

```
http://m.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=[photo-id]&prof
```

and then it magically works.

Comment: This works, but only in the mobile version :/

Do you know how work it in the desktop version ?

Answer (score 2):

The undocumented `makeprofile=1` does still work, but the user needs to have permission to view the photo in the first place. I tested this on the following public image:

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10100464869430336&set=a.575724691546.2154239.60506094&type=1&makeprofile=1

---

**Update (14 Dec 2014):**

Clicking on the above link using a Desktop browser shows me the below popup on Facebook. The feature does still work (at least for me).

[image: Profile Image Popup]

Comment: Well, previously there was a popup asking if the user wanted to change to profile pic. Now there's not. I don't see how the parameter "works". can you see any difference with and without the parameter? Cause I can't, even in your example.

Comment: Still works for me. Added screenshot as proof - tested on 17th Dec 2014.