# Profile Picture Upload using Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there any way in which I can initiate a profile picture upload on Facebook using their Javascript Graph API. I have looked in many places for an answer and the closest I had got was to [how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api/5431751#5431751). But the "makeprofile=1" does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

`&makeprofile=1` seems to be deprecated.

Use the mobile link URL instead: http://m.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=[photo-id]&prof

You'll get a screen with your picture and a button asking the user to confirm that he wants to use it as profile picture.

[image: Proof Of Concept]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480622